# Retrieve Callchain Using perf_event_open()

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, trace

How can I use `perf_event_open()` to retrieve callchain? I do not want to use the callchains provided by oprofile and perf. I want to get them directly. It seems that I need to `mmap()` the file descriptor returned by `perf_event_open()`. I do not know the size of `mmap()` and how to read from it.

Comment: Have you read [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) for `perf_event_open`? Its section *MMAP layout* describes mmap usage.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a closer look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapter 8 of [this book](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780128007266/power-and-performance) describes, by example, how to use `perf_event_open()` for both *counting* and *sampling* modes.